# Save internal table to directory as CSV file?

Tags: file-io, abap

I'm trying to save a SAP internal table to SAP Directory as .CSV file. I've learned that I should convert the contents to character type but i get an illegal casting error.
This is my code:

```
 FORM f_opendata TABLES p_tab TYPE STANDARD TABLE USING
                   p_work TYPE any.


FIELD-SYMBOLS: <lfs_wa>.


 CONCATENATE c_headerfile c_initials sy-datum c_ext INTO v_dtasetfile.

OPEN DATASET v_dtasetfile FOR OUTPUT IN TEXT MODE ENCODING UTF-8.

IF sy-subrc EQ 0.

LOOP AT p_tab INTO p_work.
  ASSIGN p_work TO <lfs_wa> CASTING TYPE c.
  TRANSFER <lfs_wa> TO v_dtasetfile.
ENDLOOP.
CLOSE DATASET v_dtasetfile.
MESSAGE i899(f2) WITH 'SUCCESS' v_dtasetfile.

ENDIF.
ENDFORM.
```

This is the error:

An exception occurred that is explained in detail below.
 The exception, which is assigned to class `CX_SY_ASSIGN_CAST_ILLEGAL_CAST`, was
 not caught in procedure `F_OPENDATA`, nor was it propagated by a RAISING clause.
 Since the caller of the procedure could not have anticipated that the
 exception would occur, the current program is terminated.
 The reason for the exception is:

> The error occurred at a statement of the form
>      ASSIGN f TO  CASTING.
>      ASSIGN f TO  CASTING TYPE t.
>    or
>      ASSIGN f TO  CASTING LIKE f1.
>    or
>      at table statements with the addition
>      ASSIGNING  CASTING.
>
> The following error causes are possible:
>    1. The type of field f or the target type determined by , t or f1
>    contains data references, object references, strings or internal tables
>    as components.
>    These components must match exactly as far as their position (offset)
>    and their type are concerned.
>    2. The specified type t or the type of f1 are not suited for the type of
>     the field symbol .
>    3. The row type of the related table is not suited for the target type
>    specified by  according to the rules described in 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a function to covert to text format before I transfered data to the dataset:

```
CALL FUNCTION 'SAP_CONVERT_TO_TEX_FORMAT'
EXPORTING
  I_FIELD_SEPERATOR          = c_colon
TABLES
  I_TAB_SAP_DATA             = ig_final
CHANGING
 I_TAB_CONVERTED_DATA       = ig_text
EXCEPTIONS
 CONVERSION_FAILED          = 1
 OTHERS                     = 2
      .
IF SY-SUBRC <> 0.
  MESSAGE ID SY-MSGID TYPE SY-MSGTY NUMBER SY-MSGNO
     WITH SY-MSGV1 SY-MSGV2 SY-MSGV3 SY-MSGV4.
  ENDIF.



OPEN DATASET v_g_dtasetfile FOR OUTPUT IN TEXT MODE ENCODING UTF-8.

IF sy-subrc EQ 0.

LOOP AT ig_text ASSIGNING <fs_l_wa>.
  TRANSFER <fs_l_wa> TO v_g_dtasetfile.
ENDLOOP.
CLOSE DATASET v_g_dtasetfile.

MESSAGE i899(f2) WITH text-020 v_g_dtasetfile text-021.

ENDIF.
```

Answer (score 1):

*Converting* isn't the same thing as *casting*. If your table contains fields that are not `CLIKE`, the system will refuse to cast the entire line. You have two options at this point:

- ensure that your output table only contains character-like fields or
- walk through each field of each line (you can use RTTI to do this) and convert the contents as required